# Using Onsen UI ons.platform isAndroidTablet()

Tags: javascript, android, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I'm working on simple hybrid app and I'm using Onsen UI using purely JavaScript, and everything is working good so far. The only issue I have is determining if the mobile device is a Tablet or Phone. I found `ons.platform` reference, and the `isAndroidTablet()` method, but I can't figure out how to use it. I used the `<ons-if orientation="landscape">` and `<ons-if platform="android">` to modify a few DOM elements when in landscape orientation and/or android, and it works great, but if I could use this `isAndroidTablet()` option, it would be great. I've been looking everywhere, but I can't find any documentation in addition to what's already on the Onsen UI pages. This is what I have so far:

```
 <ons-if orientation="landscape">
  <div id="overlay">
    <ons-scroller style="height:300px">
      <ons-list id="theList">
      </ons-list>
     </ons-scroller>
    <ons-if platform="android">I'm Android
   </ons-if>
  </div>
 </ons-if>
```

I would like to replace the `<ons-if orientation="landscape">` with something like what `isAndroidTablet()` I guess should do. Anyone out there has had any experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with `Onsen UI` but from what I seen it's based on `angular2`(or `react` or `vue`). If you use `angular`, theoretically, you could use an `*ngIf` in your template.. Like a

```
<div *ngIf="isAndroidTablet()">...</div>
```

[Here](https://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-how-to-create-pokemon-app-using-angular2-cli/#creating-components) you can find some template example with what I said earlier

Comment: Thanks  @csanonymus, I actually found the answer well hidden among Onsen UI documentation [link](https://onsen.io/v2/guide/theming.html#cross-platform-styling-autostyling). Then I just added `console.log(ons.platform.isAndroidTablet());` for testing purposes and it worked perfectly.